# java.lang.StackOverflowError. Why am I getting a Stackoverflow exception here

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a list of items that are parents and children, displayed in a hierarchy. I want to toggle their `expanded` property. so if a parent is clicked and the parent's children are showing then all of the parents children will be collapsed and vice versa

Stackoverflow trace points to this line

```
if (childItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()) {
    hideItemAndDescendants(childItem); //causing stack overflow
  }
```

I under stand that a stackoverflow occurs when a method keeps calling it self infinitely .but in this case i have a For loop that only loops over the `items` list and the list size is only around 10.

```
public boolean toggleNodeCollapseState(long itemId) {
        boolean changed = false; // a flag to determine if anything collapsed or expanded
         for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Item childItem = items.get(i);
            if (childItem.getParentItemId() == itemId) {
                changed = true;
                childItem.setCollapsed(!childItem.isCollapsed());

                if (childItem.isCollapsed()) {
                    hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);
                } else {
                    showDescendants(childItem);
                }

            }
         }
        return changed;
    }

    public void hideItemAndDescendants(Item item) {
        item.hide();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Item childItem = items.get(i);
            if (childItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()) {
                  hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);
            }
        }
    }

    public void showDescendants(Item item) {
        item.hide();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Item childItem = items.get(i);
            if (childItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()) {
                childItem.show();
                if (!childItem.isCollapsed()) {
                    showDescendants(childItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would break point on this Error in your debugger and examine the variables when this happens.  Most likely you have a circular reference in your data structure.

Comment: I would create some log statements to see the item id comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a recursive call in your hideItemAndDecendants:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    Item childItem = items.get(i);
    if (childItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()) {
          hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);
    }
}
```

So if `childItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()` you call `hideItemAndDescendants(childItem);` again. This probably causes an infinite loop causing your stackoverflowexception.

Comment: No this wouldn't cause Infinite Recursion. Had it recursed with `item` argument - `hideItemAndDescendants(item)`, then possibly it will recurse forever. So, your answer alone is not correct.

Comment: You are right. the if condition should be `childItem.getParentId() == item.getItemId()`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've got a data relationship which isn't a true tree - e.g.

```
Item1
  |
  \- Item2
       |
       \- Item1
```

At which point it would just recurse down forever. (Or more simply, an item might be its own child.)

One way of diagnosing this would be to write some output at the start of `hideItemAndDescendants` to print some identifier for "this" - I'm sure you'll see a loop somewhere.